# This C# code returns 2 different object types from a method? How is this possible?

Tags: c#, .net

Here's a screenshot of [some code from a video by Nick Chapsas](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ve__md8LeDY&t=461s) which shows the method is returning 2x different object types.

I'm showing the screenshot (instead of code) because I want to highlight how his IDE isn't complaining and it looks like it's legit:

[image]

```
public async Task<Result<Movie, ValidationFailed>> Handle(SomeCommand request, CT ct)
{
    var movie = new Movie();

    ....

    if (!validationResult.IsValid)
    {
        return new ValidationFailed(...);
    }

    ....
    return movie;
}
```

and I think his `Result` class is this:

```
    public readonly struct Result<TValue, TError>
    {
        private readonly TValue? _value;
        private readonly TError? _error;

        public Result(TValue value)
        {
            _value = value;
            _error = default;
        }

        public Result(TError error)
        {
            _error = error;
            _value = default;
        }

        public TValue? Value => _value;
        public TError? Error => _error;
        public bool IsSuccess => Error != null;
    }
```

How is this possible?

I thought he would have to do something like this:

```
    if (!validationResult.IsValid)
    {
        return new Result(new new ValidationFailed(...));
    }

    ....
    return new Result(movie);
```

Does `Movie` inherit `Result`? It doesn't look like it...

[image]

```
public partial class Movie
{
    ....
}
```

Can anyone please help?

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/253342/discussion-on-question-by-learning-postgres-this-c-code-returns-2-different-obj); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With that struct you also need to have two implicit operators like so:

```
public static implicit operator Result<TValue, TError>(TValue value) => new(value);
public static implicit operator Result<TValue, TError>(TError error) => new(error);
```

And a method to get the Result:

```
public TResult Match<TResult>(Func<TValue, TResult> value, Func<TError, TResult> error)
        => _value is not null ? value(_value) : error(_error);
```

Full code:

```
public readonly struct Result<TValue, TError>
{
    private readonly TValue _value;
    private readonly TError _error;

    public bool IsError { get; }

    public Result(TValue value)
    {
        IsError = false;
        _value = value;
        _error = default;
    }

    public Result(TError error)
    {
        IsError = true;
        _value = default;
        _error = error;
    }

    public static implicit operator Result<TValue, TError>(TValue value) => new(value);
    public static implicit operator Result<TValue, TError>(TError error) => new(error);
    public TResult Match<TResult>(Func<TValue, TResult> value, Func<TError, TResult> error)
        => _value is not null ? value(_value) : error(_error);
}
```

Comment: Correct. This type `Result<TValue, TError>` is a kind of [discriminated union](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tagged_union) that will hold _either_ a value _or_ an error, but not both. The implicit conversions make it simple to wrap either an expression of type `TValue` or one of `TError` into the `Result<,>` struct. When the C# compiler sees the type of the expression is not identical to the type declared as return type (really the type inside `Task<...>` here), then it will search for all types of implicit conversions between the types, including _user-defined_ implicit conversions like here.

Comment: love it! thanks everyone for the help and answers. Got more to learn about discriminated union's now .. but I think i like this!